# wx.Display_GetCount doesn't update when (de)activating second monitor

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an application which needs to be able to use multiple monitors. The monitors' parameters are displayed in a wx.Choice and they are updated on mouse-click on the widget.

Problem is that while the app is running if I unplug the second monitor(the os switches to single monitor mode) the wx.Display_GetCount() value doesn't change when it's called again. The same thing happens if at start there is only one monitor and then a second one is attached - the display count would not change.

I wonder if there is supposed to be an update method for wx.Display or it just isn't capable of "live"-update.

My OS: Windows 7
wxpython version: 2.8
python: 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is going to help or not, but maybe you could try and bind the wx.EVT_DISPLAY_CHANGED event in your app and then call again wx.Display.GetCount(). The information out there about this event is pretty much non-existent, while as far as I can see wx.Display.GetCount() should rebuild the list of available displays when you call it again, or at least this is what I understood from here:

http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/4582

If this doesn't happen, then maybe it's a bug in wxWidgets.

Andrea.

Comment: >wxdisplay.patch download (20.0 KB) - added by Carsten 15 months ago.
>wxdisplay_initonce.patch download (19.2 KB) - added by Carsten 15 months ago.
>    Revised patch that enumerates the monitors only once during app init (not anew on each call to GetCount())

Comment: From the above and from here: [link](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Display-class.html) I understand that GetCount() being a static method IS supposed to update(enumerate) the display list only on application init. I wonder why they keep it that way.

Comment: You should read until the end of  the comments, where it appears that GetCount re-initializes the count of monitors, or at least this is how it appears to me...

Comment: From what I understand the patch should take care of the re-init issue, but it doesn't seem to work(IF it's included in the 2.8 version, ofcourse)